# Efecto de despliegue dropdown

Tags: html, css

Tengo un header, donde tengo un dropdown y cuando le doy clic para que se desplieguen los ítems, lo hace al instante... como le hago para que tenga una animación un poco menos instantáneo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo estoy utilizando con c# asp.net
y lo que tengo en el header, lo tengo separados por otra vista donde tengo el dropdown

```
<header class="main-header">
            @*<div id="MenuArriba">*@  
                <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")"><img class="HLogo" src="~/Content/Images/HSO.png" alt="HSO" width="150" height="70" /></a>
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                            <li>
                                @*<a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>*@
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            @*</div>*@
        </header>
```

Donde mediante con el html.partial, me redirecciono a otra vista que contiene el dropdown. lo cual al hacer click me dezpliega la lista instantaneo pero ya le he buscado en varias partes y no he podido solucionar el problema.

```
<li class="dropdown user user-menu">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="~/AdminLTE/dist/img/user.svg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
            <span class="hidden-xs">@User.Identity.GetUserNameIdentifier()</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="user-header">
                <img src="~/AdminLTE/dist/img/user.svg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                <p>
                    <small>@User.Identity.GetUserEmail()</small>
                </p>
            </li>
            @*<li class="user-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <a href="#">Followers</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <a href="#">Sales</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                        <a href="#">Friends</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>*@
            <li class="user-footer">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @*<div class="pull-left">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-flat", title = "Manage" })
                    </div>*@
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Salir</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registro", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Iniciar Sesión", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        </ul>
    }
</li>
```

Comment: Olvide, estoy utilizando AdmiLTE con bootstrap

Comment: Por favor [edit] tu pregunta agregando el codigo y un [example] de lo que has intentado para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte, de lo contrario tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada

Comment: una disculpa, enseguida lo hago